# Scala.xml will be eliminated since Scala 2.11?

Tags: xml, scala

They told me, `scala.xml` has a bad performance, should not be used and will be eliminated in Scala 2.11. I can't find any proof link.

Is that so? Is there any proof link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official ["Overview of Scala 2.11"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/) page (which by the way is currently the first result of [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala.xml%20scala%202.11) for "scala.xml scala 2.11"):

> The package scala.xml has been moved out of scala-library.jar. To
>   compile code that contains XML literals, add a dependency on scala-xml
>   or your preferred alternative.

So no, "they" were wrong. There are lots of problems with `scala.xml`, but it's not going to be "eliminated" any time soon.

Comment: That's an almost impossibly vague question. It's definitely not appropriate for many applications, and in some cases that's because of performance. If you're parsing a configuration file, generating an HTML page, etc., it's probably perfectly fine.

Comment: and what if I create it and then convert to string?

Comment: It's possible? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: <someXml />.toString()

Comment: @Grienders: Yes, but what about it? That's generally something you'll only do in development / debugging, so the performance of that particular operation isn't terribly relevant to anything.